# Scale IK Bones in Armature without Affecting other bones?

Tags: armature, bones, transforms, inverse-kinematics

So I want to make my IK bones larger because they're small and hard to click.

[image]

I tried in both edit and pose mode yet noticed that affects my entire rig.

Is there a simple way to scale the IK bones only so that is doesn't affect my leg bones or move them when scaling?

[image]

After I scale then switch to pose mode my leg is moved because the joints have shifted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select your IK Bone, go to edit mode, choose "normal":

[image]

select your tail, press G Y and scale it.

[image]